# XtraGrid - Databinding two-dimensional data?

Tags: c#, data-binding, devexpress, xtragrid

I have a two-dimensional data that needs to be displayed on a grid. Each cell contains a double value identified by row and column. I can use DataTable to display the data, but I need more flexibility (an editable grid that allows user to insert/delete row or column, as well as fire cell-level value change event). I've been trying to find a way to databind two-dimensional data to gridview. I tried databinding `double[,]` and `BindingList<BindingList<double>>`. Is there a way to achieve this using XtraGrid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XtraGrid doesn't natively support such binding. There is a work-around [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E1075.aspx).

Have you considered

- Master-Detail view
- Their Pivot Grid